# Calculate change / deviation between two column values (in percent)?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a smiliar question to a lot of questions who are around here already:
[How to check change between two values (in percent)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926840/how-to-check-change-between-two-values-in-percent/30926930)

[Python calculate new column where value is by subtracting the previous date price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731947/python-calculate-new-column-where-value-is-by-subtracting-the-previous-date-pric)

I have a dataframe where i want to calculate a percentage deviation between two columns for every row:

```
A  B   diff_var
1  1    0%
1  2    100%

...
```

The problem is value A and B can have every number from -,0,+ and every combination is possible (e.g. A is negativ, B is positiv and so on). How can I make sure that I use the right calculation for it? And is there a function in python for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting the `B` column from `A` and dividing by `B` gives the relative difference. Then you can multiply by 100 and add `"%"`:

```
df["diff_var"] = df.B.sub(df.A).div(df.A).mul(100).astype(str).add("%")
```

to get

```
>>> df

   A  B diff_var
0  1  1     0.0%
1  1  2   100.0%
```

Comment: But If B is negativ (-4) and A (-1) also , this will lead to: (B-A)/A = (-4--1)/-4= -3/-4 = -0.75 which is wrong or not?

Comment: @PV8 What would you expect? I think okay but depends on you...

Comment: @PV8 Did you try `:)`? Gives `inf`, huge difference `:)`. What to put depends on you again.